# How to use AsyncTask to update a global variable

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap, android-asynctask

What I want to do: I am putting rows into a `ListView` using a custom "Location" adapter. I am trying to add a `Bitmap` into a row of the ListView. This Bitmap is coming from a URL. So, I have a global variable `public static Bitmap bitmap` and want to update this variable using an AsyncTask. Here is my code:

```
            try {
                String s = "";
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {

                                //here I am calling my new task and giving it the ID to find the image
                                BitmapWorkerTask myTask = new BitmapWorkerTask(json.getInt("ID"));
                                myTask.execute();
                                adapter.add(new Location(bitmap, json
                                        .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                                        .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                                        .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                                        .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));

                                bitmap = null;
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
            }
```

and here is my AsyncTask

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private int photoID = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(int photoID) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        this.photoID = photoID;
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        String initialURL = "http://afs.spotcontent.com/img/Places/Icons/";
        final String updatedURL = initialURL + photoID + ".jpg";
        Bitmap bitmap2 = null;

        try {
            bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    updatedURL).getContent());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap2;
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap2) {
        bitmap = bitmap2;
    }
}
```

So, for each iteration, I am feeding the AsyncTask an ID which it uses to find the image, and then (I was hoping) should update the global Bitmap which is passed into the adapter. When I run my app, the every listing's picture is empty. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `onPostExecute` return the correct bitmap for `bitmap2`? Also, shouldn't the `bitmap` variable in `onPostExecute` be accessed statically, as in ClassName.bitmap?

Comment: I'm assuming it is sending back the correct bitmap for bitmap2. The doInBackground method retrieves bitmap2 and then onPostExecute sets the global bitmap = bitmap2. Correct?

Comment: I know that the retrieval of the bitmap in doInBackground is successful because I have tried it outside of AsyncTask

Comment: Well lets just assume we don't know. Do a debug on the doInBackground or add `System.out.println()` to the exceptions in doInBackground to see if anything is happening there. Then move on.

Comment: The bitmap is being retrieved. I set an imageView = the bitmap and it worked. For some reason it isn't updating the global bitmap variable, though

Comment: @user1282637 is the BitmapWorkerTask a inner class?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes it is, but I actually got this working from OmegaDirective's answer below. Updating now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following possible order your commands get executed (remembering that tasks run in the background, so the order is non-deterministic):

1. myTask.execute()
2. BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground()
3. adapter.Add(new Location(bitmap, .......
4. BitmapWorkerTask.onPostExecute()

When you create the Location() object in step 3, the 'bitmap' object being passed is the global object pointer. Its value is NOT valid yet, because onPostExecute() wasn't called yet. So the Location object is created with a non-bitmap object. On step 4, when the bitmap is finally retrieved, the value of the global object pointer is changed (correctly), but that doesn't affect the (empty) bitmap object already passed to Location on step 2... Which is why you don't see the bitmap on your view.

What you could do is pass an additional parameter to the BitmapWorkerTask constructor: You could pass the Location object (or the underlying bitmap). From onPostExecute() you could then update that Location/bitmap object with the retrieved bitmap. You don't need a global variable here.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot, I don't know why this solution slipped past me. +1!